# Is a UUID "URL safe"?

Tags: url, uuid

Is a UUID URL safe? I want to use it as an alternate ID yet perhaps allowing access to the record as the ID in the URL. While I can use Ruby’s `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(27)` to obtain a random base64-encoded string of the same length, a UUID looks cleaner.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes.

- A [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-3) consists of only hexadecimal characters (a–f, 0–9) plus a hyphen (-).
- As per [RFC 3986 (URI Syntax) §2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3), hyphen and hexadecimal characters are included in those explicitly unreserved:

  > Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.